# AutoCompleteTextView not working after changing the Locale

Tags: java, android, arraylist, locale, autocompletetextview

In here 'AutoCompleteTextView' loads country list from 'Locale' with following code.

```
   public static ArrayList getCountryList()
        {
            Locale[] locale = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
            ArrayList<String>countries = new ArrayList<String>();
            String country = "";
            for( Locale loc : locale ){
                country = loc.getDisplayCountry();
                if( country.length() > 0 && !countries.contains(country) ){

                    countries.add( country );
                }
            }

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
                countries.add("Sri Lanka");
            }
            Collections.sort(countries, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

            return countries;

        }



@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    countryAutoTextView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.country_list_spinner_loader, getCountryList()));

    changeLanguageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(language);
            Resources res = getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = locale;
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            finish();
            Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(refresh);
      }
   });   

}
```

**country_list_spinner_loader.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/location_text_view"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_Screen_greeting_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/greeting_layout_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/main_activity_country_auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/auto_text_height"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/country_auto_text_size"
                    android:theme="@style/Autocomplete" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/time_image_view_left_margin"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

For English language it's working fine for all the Android versions. But after changing the 'Locale' language specially "Sinhala" and "Hindi" as per user preference 'AutoCompleteTextView' is not loading countries for Android Nougat(24) in real devices and also emulators.

Finally I monitor that issue with android 'Log cat' when debug-gable device has Android Nougat. That is, When 'Locale' language is English, 'Log cat' displays following and 'Auto complete text view' loaded correctly.

```
07-03 15:20:01.116 17445-17445/com.sample D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
07-03 15:20:01.119 17445-17445/com.sample D/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = com.samsung.android.hardware.context.ISemContextService$Stub$Proxy@5ba90df
07-03 15:20:01.121 17445-17445/com.sample D/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.gesture.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@40dd12c
    motionService = com.samsung.android.gesture.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@40dd12c
07-03 15:20:01.127 17445-17445/com.sample D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
07-03 15:20:01.137 17445-17445/com.sample D/ViewRootImpl@ce15bfb[PopupWindow:333598a]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=true
07-03 15:20:01.143 17445-17445/com.samplea D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=77
07-03 15:20:01.144 17445-17445/com.samplea D/ViewRootImpl@ce15bfb[PopupWindow:333598a]: setView = android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{51cd418 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} touchMode=true
07-03 15:20:01.147 17445-17445/com.sample D/ViewRootImpl@ce15bfb[PopupWindow:333598a]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
07-03 15:20:01.177 17445-17445/com.sample D/ViewRootImpl@ce15bfb[PopupWindow:333598a]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,664][1440,820] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true 491593586176} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
    mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 491593586176} hwInitialized=true
07-03 15:20:01.180 17445-17575/com.sample D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1696x412]-format:1
07-03 15:20:01.181 17445-17445/com.sample D/AbsListView:  onsize change 
07-03 15:20:01.185 17445-17445/com.sample D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
07-03 15:20:01.207 17445-17445/com.sample D/ViewRootImpl@ce15bfb[PopupWindow:333598a]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,664][1440,820] newFrame=[0,664][1440,820] result=0x1 surface={isValid=true 491593586176} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
07-03 15:20:01.218 17445-17445/com.sample D/ViewRootImpl@ce15bfb[PopupWindow:333598a]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
```

But, when 'Locale' language is "Sinhala" or "Hindi", above 'Logcat' lines are not displaying and nothing loaded to the 'Auto complete text view'.

Comment: is it only display problem  or local data is not comming ? did you check in debugger.

Comment: @ Harshal Deshmukh Yes it's a display issue, getCountryList is not null @ countryAutoTextView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.country_list_spinner_loader, getCountryList())); and also this issue is occurred only for 'Sinhala' language.

Comment: then add your xml files code here

Comment: country_list_spinner_loader<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/location_text_view"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="14sp"/> and

Comment: <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/main_activity_country_auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/auto_text_height"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/country_auto_text_size"
                    android:theme="@style/Autocomplete" />

Comment: and also above issue is occurred for "Hindi" language.

Comment: if you code contains any margin form left or right then it make to start and end

Comment: I changed it to start, but nothing

Comment: After several notes asking you to desist, you still need to read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569). Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Your code updates need to be in the question itself, and not in comments, where they are not particularly readable. I will try to put the question on hold for now, since it does not seem to contain an [mcve].

Comment: I updated my code.

Comment: Are you struggling with understanding the comments above, Nuwan? **What problem are you having understanding that we don't take begging messages?**

Comment: add `android:completionThreshold="0"` to your `AutoCompleteTextView` xml

Comment: finally I myself solved the problem. The thing is I load the country list from 'Locale []'. after changing the device language by using 'Locale' that country list set meaningless values, then 'AutoCompleteTextView' loading that false values. For solve this issue I change the loading of country list method. Anyway thankz all to help me.

Answer (score 0):

For loading country list for 'AutoCompleteTextView'.

```
final ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.country_list_spinner_loader, DataLists.getCountryList());
        countryAutoTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                Log.d("MAIN_COUNTRY_ADAPTER", "dataset changed");
                Object item = adapter.getItem(0);

                Log.d("MAIN_COUNTRY_ADAPTER", "item.toString "+ item.toString());
            }
        });
```

Instead of following method I used Hard coded countries for the list.

```
public static ArrayList getCountryList()
    {
        Locale[] locale = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        ArrayList<String>countries = new ArrayList<String>();
        String country = "";
        for( Locale loc : locale ){
            country = loc.getDisplayCountry();
           if( country.length() > 0 && !countries.contains(country) ){

               countries.add( country );            
           }
        }

       if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            countries.add("Sri Lanka");
        }
       Collections.sort(countries, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

       Log.d("DATA_LIST_CLASS", "COUNTRIES_LIST_SIZE_IS: " + countries.size() + countries.get(0) + countries.get(1));

        return countries;
    }
```

Because this also used 'Locale' to load the countries. It is an issue for changing device language and load the 'AutoCompleteTextView'.